# php file runs twice when using header for showing pdf in browser

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, header, double

strange problem. At least for me. When the link to pdf.php gets clicked, the query writes to the mysql db how many times a certain document has been clicked.

The Problem: Instead of writing "1" in the db for every click, it writes "2". It seems that the php file runs twice. But why?

```
$file = './'.mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_GET[name]).'';
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_GET[name]); /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */
$id = intval($_GET[id]);
$date = time();
$what = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_GET[name]);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);


$sql = "SELECT id,what,person_id,count FROM pdftrack WHERE id = '".$id."' AND what='".$what."'";
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis);
if ($row[id] == '') 
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pdftrack (id,what,date,count) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$what."','".$date."','1')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);//echo $sql;
    } 
else 
    {
    $count = $row[count]+1;
    $sql="UPDATE pdftrack 
    SET count='".$count."',
    date2='".$date."'
    WHERE id='".$row['id']."' 
    "; 
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    }
```

update: thanks for your help, but it still counts wrong. If the header part is gone, it works like it should. So i think it has something to do with the header part. Any ideas?

solution: using only

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
@readfile($file);
```

can´t see any downside at the moment.

Comment: What have you actually done in an attempt to solve the problem by yourself? this info can help us to help you better and faster.

Comment: What primary index do you have in pdftrack table? Probably you could put it all into single SQL statement, using ON DUPLICATE operator.

Comment: Depending on the PDF viewer used the PDF may actually be queried twice. Have you checked doing a TCP DUMP or simply inspecting some web-access log file?

Answer (score 0):

Also, was mir da sofort auffällt: Du hast eine falsche Syntax!
Wenn du auf ein assoziatives Array zugreifst (in deinem Fall $row) dann musst du den Key auch als String deklarieren. Sprich statt **$row[id]** musst du **$row['id']** verwenden. Dieser Fehler ist z.B. bei deiner ersten if-Abfrage vorhanden. Desweiteren  bei else **$row[count]** durch **$row['count']** ersetzen.

Comment: You are saying to use $row['id'] instead of $row[id], and I agree it's surely a better style, but it's not compulsory. PHP treats it just fine both ways, so anyway it's not the reason for this bug.

Comment: was previously unknown to me. For me, an array key has to be wrapped within ' or " because without it would be a constant.

Comment: You are right, it goes deeper) It will be a constant, if it's defined with such a name. Otherwise it will be treated like a string.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still counts wrong. If the header part is gone, it works like it should. So i think it has something to do with the header part. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that all variables have the expected value. Go step by step inside the script and test it with var_dump(). Also change all mistakes $row['key'] instead of $row[key]. Also make an exit() at the end of the script to prevent that another code again calls the script. Also check that the file inside readfile() is not the php-script

Comment: If nothing helps please post the full script so that we can test the script ourself